# How to calculate percentages in a stacked barplot bar-wise?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

### Problem

The current percentages in the bar are calculate with the total amount of data. I want to each stack to have a fully 100%. (Solved)

Also the percentages should be rounded to the nearest integer. (Solved)

**Edit**: Remove all percentages below or equal to 1. (Solved)

**Edit2**: Make sure no labels are overlapping.

I've been googling for a while now. It seems like there isn't a proper way to prevent labels overlapping.

Possible solutions I discovered:

- Flip the plot
- Add angle() to rotate the labels
- "Manually" calculate each position
- Make use of check_overlap = TRUE

### Current State

[image: Current State]

### My Code so far

```
# Load libraries & packages =================================
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library("dplyr")
library("foreign")
library("tidyverse")
library("forcats")


# Data setup =================================
spss_file_path <- "D:\\Programming\\Testing\\2017-03-15_data_import&ggplot2\\Beispieldatensatz(fiktiv).sav"
exampledata <- read.spss(spss_file_path, use.value.labels = TRUE,
                         to.data.frame = TRUE, reencode = TRUE)


exampledata$V43   <- factor(exampledata$V43,
                            levels = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                            labels = c("1 Sehr zufrieden","2","3","4", "5 Sehr unzufrieden"))

exampledata$V43   <- factor(exampledata$V43, levels = rev(unique(levels(exampledata$V43))))
exampledata$A_REF <- factor(exampledata$A_REF, levels = rev(unique(levels(exampledata$A_REF))))
exampledata$V101  <- factor(exampledata$V101, levels = rev(unique(levels(exampledata$V101))))

labels <- exampledata %>% 
  filter(!is.na(V101), !is.na(V43)) %>% 
  count(A_REF) %>% 
  mutate(labels = paste(A_REF,"(n=", n, ")")) %>% 
  select(A_REF, labels)

plot_data <-  exampledata %>% 
  filter(!is.na(V101), !is.na(V43)) %>% 
  left_join(labels, by = "A_REF")

plot_data <- plot_data %>% 
  group_by(labels) %>% 
  summarize(`5 Sehr unzufrieden` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "5 Sehr unzufrieden", 1, 0)) / n(),
            `4` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "4", 1, 0)) / n(),
            `3` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "3", 1, 0)) / n(),
            `2` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "2", 1, 0)) / n(),
            `1 Sehr zufrieden` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "1 Sehr zufrieden", 1, 0)) / n()) %>%
  gather(key = Rating, value = prop, -labels)

plot_data$labels <- factor(plot_data$labels)
plot_data$Rating <- factor(plot_data$Rating) %>% fct_rev()

# Plot =================================
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = labels, y = prop, fill = Rating)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)) +
  labs(y=NULL, x=NULL, fill=NULL) + 
  ggtitle(paste(attr(exampledata, "variable.labels")[77])) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = if_else(prop > 0.02, scales::percent(round(prop, 2)), NULL)), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

### Data

```
structure(list(exampledata.V101 = structure(c(2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Weiblich", "Männlich"), class = "factor"), exampledata.A_REF = structure(c(18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 
16L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
16L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
16L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 
16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 18L), .Label = c("Zertifikat eines Aufbau- oder Ergänzungsstudiums", 
"LA Berufliche Schulen", "LA Sonderschule", "LA Gymnasium", "LA Haupt- und Realschule", 
"LA Grundschule", "Künstlerischer/musischer Abschluss", "Kirchlicher Abschluss", 
"Staatsexamen (ohne Lehramt)", "Diplom Fachhochschule, Diplom I an Gesamthochschulen", 
"Diplom Universität, Diplom II an Gesamthochschulen", "Sonstiges", 
"Promotion", "Staatsexamen", "Magister", "Diplom", "Master", 
"Bachelor"), class = "factor"), exampledata.V43 = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("5 Sehr unzufrieden", "4", "3", "2", 
"1 Sehr zufrieden"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("exampledata.V101", 
"exampledata.A_REF", "exampledata.V43"), row.names = c(NA, 100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can shorten the calculation of percentages as follows: `plot_data <- plot_data %>% group_by(labels, V43) %>% tally %>% mutate(Percent = n/sum(n))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually preferable to manipulate your data into summarized data before charting it. I find that trying to have `ggplot2` do the summarization for you is either limited or difficult to have it shown the way you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
```

Because it's best to summarize your data before plotting it in `ggplot2`, the following bit of code calculates the proportion withing each group of `label` that selected a particular answer on the scale. In the final step I turned the data from wide to long, so that all the proportions to be charted are in the same variable (which I call `prop`).

```
plot_data <- plot_data %>% group_by(labels) %>% 
            summarize(`5 Sehr unzufrieden` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "5 Sehr unzufrieden", 1, 0)) / n(),
                      `4` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "4", 1, 0)) / n(),
                      `3` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "3", 1, 0)) / n(),
                      `2` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "2", 1, 0)) / n(),
                      `1 Sehr zufrieden` = sum(ifelse(V43 == "1 Sehr zufrieden", 1, 0)) / n()) %>%
            gather(key = Rating, value = prop, -labels)
```

It's preferable that categorical variables are set as factors for manipulating, say, the order and the colours, so this is what the following does. Initially, my code had the scale labels (which I called `Rating` in the `gather` function above) go in the reverse order than what you had, so I'm using `fct_rev` from the `forcats` package to reverse it back.

```
plot_data$labels <- factor(plot_data$labels)
plot_data$Rating <- factor(plot_data$Rating) %>% fct_rev()
```

For the chart below, I just made a couple of changes. The most notable is that I'm using `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`. In the background, `geom_col` is the same as `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` - it's just quicker to type. We're essentially telling `ggplot2` to chart the data as is instead of treating it like raw data. However, I do need to specify the `y` aesthetic to indicate what data I want charted, so I'm specifying to use the `prop` variable in the initial `ggplot` call.

```
# Plot =================================
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = labels, y = prop, fill = Rating)) +
geom_col() + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)) +
labs(y=NULL, x=NULL, fill=NULL) + 
ggtitle(paste(attr(exampledata, "variable.labels")[77])) + 
theme_classic() + 
geom_text(aes(label = if_else(prop > 0.01, scales::percent(round(prop, 2)), NULL)), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5)) +
coord_flip()
```

The only other line I changed is the `geom_text` call above. I added an `if_else` function so that it either shows the label (if it's above 1%) or not (1% or less). Also, I rounded the percentage so that you don't have any decimals using the `round` function. Remember that you need to round to 2 decimal points.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! It's working fine, but I'd like to remove all percentage below 1%. Since I have no clue what you have done, it would be nice if you could provide me some explanation/help.

You couldn't achieve the sample sizes since I gave you only the first 100 rows of my data.

Comment: @MarcBrinkmann I added some extra explanation, and amended the `geom_text` code to remove labels that are 1% or less.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm receiving the following messages: Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: position Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type PositionFill/PositionStack/Position/ggproto. Defaulting to continuous. Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (15): label, position, x, y, fill

Comment: Hi @MarcBrinkmann Try again with the revised `ggplot` code above? Brackets were in the wrong spot within the `geom_text` layer, leading to the error. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will get you towards where you want to go, but here's a simple version based on some code I made a little way back. Didn't include all the ggplot2 bits as I agree with @Phil that the summary should be done before plotting.

```
devtools::install_github("ekstroem/MESS")
x <- c(35, 34.6, 12, 5, .1, .99, 1.2, 11.11)  # Input percentages

round_percent(x)
```

which gives

```
[1] 35 35 12  5  0  1  1 11
```

or you could have

```
round_percent(x[x>1])
```

which gives

```
[1] 36 35 12  5  1 11
```

You'd need to make sure the colouring matches the remaining groups tho' so there is still some work left.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution approach. I always like to have multiple options to solve a given problem.