# ggplot - grouped barplot for 2x2 table

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a 2x2 contingency table with the counted numbers in cells, how can I get a grouped bar plot with stacked percentages?

Here is some example code:

```
species=c(rep("sorgho" , 1) , rep("poacee" , 1)  )
condition=rep(c("normal" , "stress") ,1)
value=abs(rnorm(4 , 0 , 4))
data2=data.frame(species,condition,value)

library(ggplot2)

# Stacked Percent
ggplot(data2, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=species)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity", position="fill")
```

But my data looks like:

```
        A B
Group C 4 5
      D 1 2
```

The plot should tell me: What percentage of A is in Group C, and what percentage of B is in Group D?

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to transform your data to the right format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate percentages in a stacked barplot bar-wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212067/how-to-calculate-percentages-in-a-stacked-barplot-bar-wise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
data <- matrix(c(4, 1, 5, 2), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("C", "D"), c("A", "B")))
data_m <- melt(data, varnames = c("Exp", "Obs"), id.vars = "Exp")

ggplot(data_m %>% group_by(Exp) %>% 
           mutate(perc = round(value/sum(value),2)), 
       aes(x = Exp, y = perc, 
           fill = Obs, cumulative = TRUE)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(perc*100,"%")), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely! That's what I meant. Many thanks. Could you pls add: library(dplyr) into your code?